# How to combine various measures into a single measure

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, vector, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I have several measures:

1. Profit and loss (PNL).
2. Win to loss ratio (W2L).
3. Avg gain to drawdown ratio (AG2AD).
4. Max gain to maximum drawdown ratio (MG2MD).
5. Number of consecutive gains to consecutive losses ratio (NCG2NCL).

If there were only 3 measures (A, B, C), then I could represent the "total" measure as a magnitude of a 3D vector:

R = SQRT(A^2 + B^2 + C^2)

If I want to combine those 5 measures into a single value, would it make sense to represent them as the magnitude of a 5D vector? Is there a way to put more "weight" on certain measures, such as the PNL? Is there a better way to combine them?

**Update:**
I'm trying to write a function (in C#) that takes in 5 measures and represents them in a linear manner so I can collapse the multidimensional values into a single linear value. The point of this is that it will allow me to only use one variable (save memory) and it will provide a fast method of comparison between two sets of measures. Almost like building a hash value, but each hash can be used for comparison (i.e. >, <, ==).

The statistical significance of the values is the same as the order they're listed: PNL is the most significant while NCG2NCL is the least significant.

Comment: Umm, isn't this an entirely domain-specific problem?  You can combine a set of numbers in an infinite number of ways; I'm not sure what this has to do with programming or algorithms...

Comment: I don't think the question could is as relevant as should you.

Comment: @Oli, I'm trying to program it :), so that's why I think there must be some sort of algorithm or method to represent a "multidimensional vector" with a linear value (i.e. magnitude). I need to be able to compare the "magnitudes of two vectors" in a meaningful way, so there must be some widely accepted ways to do that.

Comment: @Lirik: Like I said, there are all sorts of ways.  It's not possible to recommend a *good* or *meaningful* purely one from a programming perspective; you need to understand the problem domain (i.e. finance) to make a sensible decision.

Comment: And this probably belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jared, so many stack exchanges :)...

Comment: If you just want to compare the values, there is no need to do a SQRT.

Comment: @Lirik - Yes, no kidding. My own thinking is, you'll need to find out what the statistical significance of each measure you're wanting to determine (weighting, for instance), and what it means in combination, and then maybe validate your math, before turning it into a algorithm. So it's putting the whip in front of the cart in front of the horse to work on the algorithm first.

Comment: @Jared, the statistical significance is the same as the order I listed the measures in: PNL has the highest statistical value, while NCG2NCL has the lowest statistical value. Like Nikita said: the magnitude of (9,0,0) is 9 and magnitude of (3,3,3) is 5.196, but simply adding the values would make the vectors look equivalent.

Comment: If you had training data you could train an SVM and let it figure out which measures are most important.  In that case your question could go on one of the machine-learning-oriented stack exchange type sites :)

Comment: @Hightechrider, thanks! 1-up for referring me to a "more appropriate" stack exchange site :). Anyway, I might just throw a bunch of values in Excel and see how they get distributed when I apply the suggested solutions... if I have any problems, I'll just go to the Excel-oriented stack exchange :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If I want to combine those 5 measures into a single value, would it make sense to represent them as the magnitude of a 5D vector?*
Absolutely, if result suits you.

*Is there a way to put more "weight" on certain measures, such as the PNL?*
You can introduce constant weights

```
SQRT(wa*A^2 + wb*B^2 + wb*C^2)
```

*Is there a better way to combine them?*
That depends on your requirements. In particular, there's nothing wrong with using simple sum `|A| + |B| + |C|`, that would favour 'average' properties better. I.e., with your formula `(0, 0, 9)` gives much better total than `(3, 3, 3)`, while with the simple sum they would be equivalent.

Generally speaking **Oli** is right: you'll have to make the decision yourself, no algorithm book can evaluate the requirements for you.

Comment: thanks! I don't know if I didn't explain my problem sufficiently well, but you're definitely supporting my hypothesis: the magnitude formula gives a much better total than just adding the numbers. I was trying to think of a better total, i.e. something like a hash number, are hash numbers ever used to give a sort order for the thing they're representing?

Comment: @Lirik Hash values are distributed 'randomly'. E.g., for a vector `(0, 0, 1)` you could have hash `10000` and for vector `(100, 100, 100)` hash `3`. Does that suit you? If yes, go ahead :)

Comment: @Lirik "Better" in what sense? There's no general "better", but there might be "better" for your particular requirements.

Comment: by better I mean that the vectors are always represented by a single value that properly reflects the significance of the measures (where PNL has the highest significance and NCG2NCL has the lowest). So far I think that the vector magnitude with weights attached to each value will be sufficient... I don't plan on using a hash value, but I was just brainstorming.

Answer (score 1):

Combining measures into a single value is risky at best.  However you do it you loose information.  If I have 3 oranges, an apple and a couple of slices of bread I can combine them in various ways:

- Sum (3 + 1 + 2 ) = 6
- Weighted sum ( .5 * 3 + 2 * 1 + 1.5 * 2) = 6.5
- SQRT( 3 ^ 2 + 1 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 2) = SQRT ( 15 ) ~= 3.8
- SQRT( 3 ^ 2 + 2 * 1 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 2) = SQRT (16) = 4
- and on and on.

Whichever result I get is less meaningful than the first. Through in a steak and a glass of water and the value becomes even less meaningful.  The result is always some measure of serving of food.

You need to figure out how to convert your various values into values with equivelent scales (linear or log) and equivalent value (1 X ~= 1 Y  ~= 1Z).  At that point a simple sum or product may be sufficient.  In your case, it appears you are trying to combine various measure of financial return.  Some of the measures you are using are not highly comparable.

Comment: thanks, so far it seems like the weighted vector magnitude provides the most "resolution." For my purposes, its results seem to "better" distinguish the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there are an infinite number of ways of combining values. You've tagged the question machine-learning and artificial-intelligence, which suggests you might want to find the optimum way of combining them? Eg. come up with a "goodness" metric, and try to model this from the others. Then there are a range of machine learning algorithms - eg. a Bayesian Model would be a good start: Fast, generally performs well if not necessarily the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing this using principal component analysis. That will give you the weights you need for your coefficients.  You can either do this via a stat package or use a packaged C# function.

-Ralph Winters